# Autosys job not running every 15 mins

Tags: autosys

I created new JIL with following details to run job every 15 mins, however first time i started job using `Force Start Event`. Dont see job running even half hour after last run.

Following is my JIL:

```
insert_job: <job_name>    job_type: cmd
description: <job_descript>
machine: <server>
owner: <owner>
max_run_alarm: 0
alarm_if_fail: y
days_of_week: all
start_mins: 0,15,30,45
profile: <server-profile>
std_out_file: <output-log-location>
std_err_file: <error-log-location>
command: <shell-file-to-execute>
```

Please assist

Answer (score 0):

Found out issue:

Following attribute was not set as a result autosys was not able to recognize date and time:

```
date_conditions: 1
```

**date_conditions:  Toggle which must be set in order for date/time
attributes to be recognized by AutoSys**